# Как сделать ссылку на произвольный адрес на карту из конструктора Яндекс Карт?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, карты

Делаю чат бота для доставки еды. Идея: клиент отправляет боту адрес, бот делает из него ссылку на мою карту из конструктора с уже введённым адресом клиента.

Нашла такое решение [https://yandex.ru/maps/?text=Жуковский, ул. Маяковского, 9](https://yandex.ru/maps/?text=%D0%96%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9,%20%D1%83%D0%BB.%20%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%8F%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE,%209) , но нужно привязать [конкретную карту](https://yandex.ru/maps/?um=constructor%3Aede2cab0fe593c417a1cfb2415cbafdb9950900e74d0cc048b642be27eab23f1&source=constructorLink).

Возможно ли это?
Понимаю, что скорее всего нужно спросить по отдельности населённый пункт, улицу и дом, забить в переменные и вставить в ссылку. Но как и куда?

P.S. Я не программист, я дизайнер :)

Answer (score 0):

Просто объедините основные параметры из ссылок.

Показать определённый адрес можно по [инструкции](https://yandex.ru/dev/yandex-apps-launch/maps/doc/concepts/yandexmaps-web.html#yandexmaps-web__search) параметром **text** (пробелы стоит заменять на **%20**). А за конкретную карту конструктора отвечает его код **um**, который можно скопировать из URL'а открытой по ссылке карты [Конструктора](https://yandex.ru/map-constructor/).

Таким образом можно открыть нужный адрес на вашей карте по такой ссылке:
[https://yandex.ru/maps/?um=constructor%3Aede2cab0fe593c417a1cfb2415cbafdb9950900e74d0cc048b642be27eab23f1&text=Жуковский,%20ул.%20Маяковского,%209](https://yandex.ru/maps/?um=constructor%3Aede2cab0fe593c417a1cfb2415cbafdb9950900e74d0cc048b642be27eab23f1&text=%D0%96%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9,%20%D1%83%D0%BB.%20%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%8F%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE,%209)